# How to access the passed prop array inside the child component

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to access an array of venues as a state prop from the parent into the child component file. The array 'Venues' has a set of properties each like venue.name and venue.location.address

I can see that the prop has been successfully passed but when I try to map the array (as name): it just shows the number of items in the array and the array passed in the div 'code' itself is null.

```
import DropDown from './DropDown.js';

class App extends Component {

  state = {
    venues : []
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getVenues()
  }
```

The venue locations are from a third party API below

```
  getVenues = () => {
    const endPoint = "https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/explore?"
    const parameters = {
      client_id: "CFSJXP",
      query: "Outdoors & Recreation",
      near: "Singapore",
      v: "20200404"
    }
   })

  }

  render() {
    return (

               <DropDown dataFromApp = {this.state.venues} />

      )
  }
}
```

Then in the Component file

````
  render () {
    return (

        <section>
          <h4>Location details</h4>
         ``` <div className='code'>
            {this.props.dataFromApp.map((item,venue) => <li key={venue}>{item}</li>)}
          </div> ```
        </section>
      </section>
    )
  }
````

And when I try to stringify the array the following error is thrown:

> Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {reasons, 
>           venue, referralId}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use 
>           an array instead.

How can I pass the prop data into the div 'code' and then display its data on the sidebar?

Comment: Where is `setState()` ?

Comment: How are you fetching data? How you are storing data in state?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here only,

```
{this.props.dataFromApp.map((item,venue) => <li key={venue}>{item}</li>)}
```

You are directly trying to render `item` which is a `object` and not a plain data.

Your error also stating the same,

> (found: object with keys {reasons, venue, referralId})

It means that `item = {reasons="", venue="", referralId=""}`

You must do something like this,

```
{this.props.dataFromApp.map(item => <li key={item.referralId}>{item.venue}</li>)}
```

Comment: This is it! Thanks a lot.
Just added the name property after the item.venue

{this.props.dataFromApp.map(item => <li key={item.referralId}>{item.venue.name}</li>)}

Comment: Yes it depends on your data structure.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 <div className='code'>
            {this.props.dataFromApp.map((item,venue) => <li key={venue}>{item.venue}</li>)}
 </div>
```

Comment: There is change he is using `item.venue` instead of `item` in `li` value.

Comment: This answer is not based to the code but just to a supposition

Answer (score 0):

wrap state inside a constructor

```
constructor(){
  super();
  this.state = {
    venues : []
  };
}
```

in getVenues() function set the venues using

```
this.setState({ venues: // the response from the third party API });
```

Answer (score 0):

Error says that you are rendering an object in DOM, you can't do that you have to render single key of object or to render multiple keys you have to iterate over keys.

Your mistakes

1. Firstly, You are not storing data in local state. use `this.setState({venues : [response array here]})`
2. Secondly, you should define key of venue object in `<li key={venue}>{item}</li>` like this `<li key={venue}>{item.key}</li>`